# Why the number of images are not same when using .size() command and by using 'Inspector' tool in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagery

```
var tiles = ['42RUN'];

var ImageryCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .select('B[2-8]', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12')
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', tiles))
  .filterDate(2018-12-14, 2023+'-04-30')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5));

var count1A = ImageryCollection.size();
print('No. of Images:', count1A);

print(ImageryCollection);
Map.addLayer(ImageryCollection);
```

In the **Console**, the number of images as a result of .size() command results in 276 images. But when I pick inspector tool and click on the loaded images below in **Layer View** section, it shows different number of images on clicking different pixels of images.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The number of images in the collection is the one reported by `ee.ImageCollection.size()` which in your case is 276. The number reported by the inspector tool includes only the images which footprint includes the point that you have clicked on. This number will vary depending on where you click. If you click on an area outside any of the images, you will see:

`Layer 1: No unmasked pixels at clicked point.`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have diagnosed the problem here. But I am still looking for the solution. My ultimate goal is to classify and detect the changes in the temporal-series imagery collection. But if this problem persists, classification results of each of the image will vary poles apart.

Actually, some of the images are of complete swath width i.e., 100Kmx100Km but others includes missing data pixels.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).